# Two files with same path and name - corrupted file system?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, ntfs, wget

My computer is running windows XP 32 bit. I am using the following script to download the contents of a website to my hard drive, which is formatted as NTFS.

```
wget-1.10.2.exe -r -x -p -nc -c -e robots=off http://lit.gfax.ch/
```

The problem is that I've noticed that it seems to be downloading some of the files twice, even though it shouldn't be doing that with these parameters.

So I ran `SpaceSniffer.exe` (a tool for visualizing the space on the HDD) to see what's going on and surprisingly it shows that some files exist TWICE. These files have the same file path and same file name, so in windows explorer I only see one file, but the duplicate file really does take up space on the drive according to SpaceSniffer and also according to the folder properties in Windows which shows the same size as SpaceSniffer.

So what's going on? And how can I get to these duplicate files to delete them?

Comment: Have you run a check for disk corruption (`chkdsk`)?  Have you tried any utilities other than this single "SpaceSniffer" utility (maybe it's just faulty)?

Comment: Yes I did, and it found a few problems, but (1) for some reason it's not fixing them, and (2) the number of problems found seems far too small compared to the number of duplicated files I know exists.

Comment: @Malki Well, if there are errors on your hard dirve, you may have to consider the posibility of it beeing faulty